# How to resize SDWebImage before Cache, considering UIImageView size

Tags: ios, caching, resize, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage to load and cache Images I am loading into my tableViewCells. I want to resize the images in order to get better scrolling performance and wrote a resize function as extension to UIImageView, that resizes the images to the size of its imageView. Searching for a solution I found the SDWebImageManager function that can be used to resize an Image before caching it, the only problem is that the parameter is a UIImage, so I can't resize it to fit the ImageView it is in. I hope you guys got what I mean. That's how I am doing it at the moment, which is kinda bad for performance, cause it gets resized every time the cell is displayed. size is the size of the ImageView of course.

```
cell.firstImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image0Uri), completed: { (img, err, cache, url) in
                    cell.firstImage.resize(toSize: size)
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more complicated than just 1 line of code, you might have to manually load the image, then resize it, then save it to cache with your own key, then fetch the lower reso with your key

Maybe something like this:

```
SDImageCache.shared().queryCacheOperation(forKey: "KEY", done: { (image, data, type) in
        if let image = image {
            self.firstImage.image = image
        } else {
            if let imgUrl = url {
                SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: URL(string: imgUrl), options: [], progress: nil) { (image, data, error, type, done, url) in
                    image.resize(toSize: size)
                    self.firstImage.image = image
                    SDImageCache.shared().store(image, forKey: "KEY", completion: nil)
                })
            } else {
                self.firstImage.image = UIImage(named: "img_default")
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure how to implement it with SDWebImage..  I will try your version, seems to be the right one, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I finally tried it and it seems to work perfectly :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image after getting it. Just Pass Image and the Height and Width of Image.

```
[cell.imgview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Image_URL2]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] completed:^(UIImage image, NSError error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                if (image) {
                    cell.imgview.image=[Utility compressImageDynamic:image hight:(360  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)/320 width:(360  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)/320];

                }
                else{

                }
            }];
```

Below is the Function for reSize image.

```
-(UIImage )compressImageDynamic:(UIImage )image hight:(float)x width:(float)y{
float actualHeight = image.size.height;
float actualWidth = image.size.width;
float maxHeight = x;
float maxWidth = y;
float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
float maxRatio = maxWidth/maxHeight;
float compressionQuality = 1;//50 percent compression

if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth){
    if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
        //adjust width according to maxHeight
        imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
        actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
        actualHeight = maxHeight;
    }
    else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
        //adjust height according to maxWidth
        imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
        actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
        actualWidth = maxWidth;
    }
    else{
        actualHeight = maxHeight;
        actualWidth = maxWidth;
    }
}else{
    actualHeight = maxHeight;
    actualWidth = maxWidth;
    compressionQuality = 1;
}

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

}

Comment: Thats almost exactly what I am already doing, the problem is that the original image is cached isn't it? I wanna cache the resized image, so I don't have to call the resize function again and again