# How to resize image already saved in cache using SDWebImage?

Tags: swift, swift5, sdwebimage

I would like to be able to do 2 things:

1. Update the cached image with a new size
2. Catch a new image fetched from the cloud and resize it before saving it in cache.

I guess that if I am able to to #1, I will be able to do #2.

The code that I use to load image looks like this:

```
let manager = SDWebImageManager(cache: SDImageCache.shared, 
                                loader: StorageImageLoader.shared)
manager.loadImage(with: NSURL.sd_URL(with: ref) as URL?,
                  options: [],
                  progress: nil) {(image, _, error, _, _, _) in
```

So, the `image` is the one that I need. I can check its size.

Now, if I needed to resize it, how can I update the cache with that new size?

I looked around and found there is a `SDImageResizingTransformer` function, but does not seem to be used to change the cached version. Only to resize it when needed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44303730/4321277). It looks like promising, but don't understand what "KEY" I should use. I left as is, but does not seem to update the cache correctly because each time I need to resize it.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use `ref.absoluteString` as a `"KEY"`? Unrelated, but instead of `NSURL.sd_URL(with: ref) as URL?`, `URL.sd_URL(with: ref)` doesn't work?

Comment: @Larme, using "ref.absoluteString" gives me "Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'absoluteString'". I will try with ref.name instead. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know what's `ref`, but then `NSURL.sd_URL(with: ref).absoluteString`, but note that it could be the URL where is save initially the image from SDWebImage (to check).

Comment: @Larme, for your info, in my case, `ref` is the `StorageReference`. Regarding the `ref.name`, it looks like it is working. I will need to do more test, but so for so good.